# Angular Material Mat Table Limit Columns And Rows From Api Response

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can we limit Mat Table columns and rows.

```
  <mat-table   [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-table">
    <span *ngFor="let data of displayedColumns; let i=index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i<5" matColumnDef="{{data}}">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{data}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[data]}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </span>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns.slice(0,5)"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row (click)="getRecord(BackupId1,row.objname)" *matRowDef="let row; 
    columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

We can limit displayed columns array in TypeScript but I want to do in template.

Answer (score -1):

There's the [`slice` pipe in Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) for this purpose.

From the docs:

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li *ngFor="let i of collection | slice:1:3">{{i}}</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Comment: Problem in mat-header-row, how can we limit column names. Getting Could not find column with id "Id".